# Redirect all 404 errors with 301 to index/homepage with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I know there are a few answers in the web, but none of them worked for me. For example I tried this, but ends up in 403 error for every page.

For your information I am hosting on domainfactory and I asked them, but they do not offer help for it. So I am not sure, if its not working out of this specific hoster, or this code is just not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

I know its not always best to redirect all to homepage, but in my case it is. So I am looking to redirect all 404 to my homepage.

Comment: What is exact problem with your rule?

Comment: Yesterday it was causing a 403 error on every page. Now I put it at the beginning instead of somewhere else in the htaccess. Now its working. Strange.